# How can I remove the SIM Lock on my Samsung S2 LTE (SC-03D) Japan Docomo?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, sim-unlocking

I am looking for a way to make the phone sim free without going to the company's shop and paying for them to unlock it. Anybody know how it can be done? The SC-03D does not have an nv_data.bin file that most galaxy unlocking tools require so I'm at a bit of a loss. It does have an /efs/ partition though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way and posted a solution to xda-dev:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=60964832&postcount=2

In order to sim unlock the SC-03D it is necessary to first flash a "special" radio. Flashing the radio is possible with a CWM based recovery. Get the latest version of CWM-recovery from this forum and flash it using ODIN/Heimdall:
http://android.slateblue.tk/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=73

Then get the radio to flash from this XDA thread:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=37564563)

This radio is from the Galaxy Note (SC-05D) so it made my phone very very slow. However, you need this radio because it has options to make the phone sim free. Options which the original SC-03D radio does not. As soon as you flash this new radio boot the phone, run the dialer application and dial:

*#9090#

it might be very slow but eventually you should get to the service menu.
To access more options press [menu] then [Input key]. Then into the text box type:

Q0 (Q Zero, not QOh)

It should bring you to another menu after a second or so. Select these options:

[1] DEBUG SCREEN
[8] PHONE CONTROL
[5] SIMULATION
[6] NETWORK LOCK
[3] PERSO SHA256 OFF
Wait for 30 seconds , press MENU then BACK.
Select:
[4] NW LOCK NV DATA INITIALLIZ

Wait 60 seconds. Reboot.
Congrats you're sim free. You should remain sim free no matter what radio/firmware/rom you flash.

partial credit to FAB: 
http://blogs.yahoo.co.jp/fab4_boys/26754215.html
And HomuHomu for the recovery.